# Entity Framework Add/Update works, cannot Read

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have a class with this getter:

```
public ObjectSet<PolicyNumberBound> PolicyNumbersBound
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_PolicyNumbersBound == null))
                {
                    _PolicyNumbersBound = base.CreateObjectSet<PolicyNumberBound>("PolicyNumbersBound");
                }
                return _PolicyNumbersBound;
            }
        }

        private ObjectSet<PolicyNumberBound> _PolicyNumbersBound;
```

This class is defined like this:

`public partial class PolicyNumberBound : EntityObject`

Is this enough for a get to work? There's plenty of entries in the database, but this is always null:

```
var oldPolicyNumber = lDataBase.PolicyNumbersBound.ToList().Last();
```

There are other entity types set up in a nearly identical fashion that are functional. Please provide insight on what I'm missing.

Using Entity Framework 4.1.10715.0